# Remove Log4net (null): Conditional Output

Tags: log4net

I'm trying to suppress "(null)" output.  If I have this conversionPattern:

```
%property{MyProp}
```

...and if MyProp is null, then the output is:

```
(null)
```

In most cases that is good.  But what if I don't want the "(null)" to be output?  Can this be done?

The problem becomes more interesting if my conversionPattern looks like this:

```
MY_PROP=%property{MyProp}
```

In this case, even if I find a way to suppress the "(null)", my output will still be:

```
MY_PROP=
```

Ideally, I'd like to suppress everything related to "my prop" if the value is null.  If I invented my own syntax, it might be:

```
%(MyProp,MY_PROP=%MyProp)
```

This would make log4net suppress the conversion pattern specified in the second parameter, if the first parameter was null.

My musings aside, is there a *real* way to do this in log4net?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a custom `PatternLayoutConverter`. If the property value is `null` write the `customNullReplacement` (that can even be based on the `Option` key if you want some dynamism).

```
namespace LogUtils
{
    public class CustomNullProperty : PatternLayoutConverter
    {
        private static string customNullReplacement = "????";
        override protected void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            if (Option != null)
            {
                var prop = loggingEvent.LookupProperty(Option);
                if(prop == null)
                {
                    prop = customNullReplacement;
                }
                WriteObject(writer, loggingEvent.Repository, prop);
            }
            else
            {
                WriteDictionary(writer, loggingEvent.Repository, loggingEvent.GetProperties());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You then define this converter – using the `<converter>` tag – on the Log4Net Configuration (XML based config example bellow) and use it on your `conversionPattern`:

```
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <converter>
         <name value="customNullProp" />
         <type value="LogUtils.CustomNullProperty, DLLNAME" />
     </converter>
    <conversionPattern value="customNullProp{PropertyName} %message%newline"/>
 </layout>
```

There are other approaches like creating a renderer for `System.Object` but I find this approach more explicit.

For your second requirement, using the custom converter, you could simply move the prefix inside the custom `converter` writer.